# Regex linux bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed

What I basically need is a regex to only get the domain and port `lb.geo.pirlpool.eu:8002` in both of the following:

```
-epool stratum+tcp:\/\/lb.geo.pirlpool.eu:8002

-epool lb.geo.pirlpool.eu:8002
```

I managed to get everything before with the following regex: `(\-epool (.*:\\\/\\\/)?)` , but I need to remove it or to get everything after the matched string, but excluding it. I need to do this in linux bash / sed.

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/VE0sX6/1)

Comment: Where is this text coming from? Is it stored in a variable?

Comment: from a pipe from cat. I can store it if that helps. It is a bash script

Comment: you need to get it, or remove it? you should give some sample inputs and sample outputs with nontrivial distinction between them for us to capture your idea.

Comment: Try `sed`: [`sed -E 's/^.*(:\\\/\\\/|[[:blank:]])//'`](https://ideone.com/0eiwU9)

Comment: I need to get the domain and port. Remove the rest or get everything from it to finish

Comment: ... why are you piping cat? This feels like an XY problem.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you saved me :) 10x. I can take that as an answer

Comment: @melpomene Actually, we are using sed a lot in our Bash scripts, so I suggested a natural tool for *replacement*. I converted the same logic into Bash just as a proof of concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `sed` to remove the parts of a string you do not want. In this scenario, you need to match any text up to the last `://` or a whitespace. Thus, you may use

```
sed -E 's/.*(:\\\/\\\/|[[:blank:]])//'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/0eiwU9)

**Details**

- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible, up to the last
- `(:\\\/\\\/|[[:blank:]])` - either of the 2 alternatives:

  - `:\\\/\\\/` - a `://` substring
  - `|` - or
  - `[[:blank:]]` - a horizontal whitespace.

Note the `-E` option that makes the regex engine parse the pattern as an ERE POSIX compliant pattern.

You may actually reproduce the same logic in Bash:

```
s='-epool lb.geo.pirlpool.eu:8002'
if [[ $s = *":\\/\\/"* ]]; then
  s="${s//*:\\\/\\\//}"
else
  s="${s//*[[:blank:]]/}"
fi
echo "$s"
```

See [another online demo](https://ideone.com/712ev7).

Answer (score 1):

with bash and dash

```
s='-epool lb.geo.pirlpool.eu:8002';echo ${s##*[ /]}
```

lb.geo.pirlpool.eu:8002

```
s='-epool stratum+tcp:\/\/lb.geo.pirlpool.eu:8002';echo ${s##*[ /]}
```

lb.geo.pirlpool.eu:8002

Comment: There is one gotcha with the single char (and why I did not even consider posting anything similar): it will return unwanted results if the domain name is followed with subparts, like [`s='-epool http://lb.geo.pirlpool.eu:8002/something';echo ${s##*[ /]}`](https://ideone.com/MxbWud). It is safer to check a `://` as a sequence of chars.